# Filtering route with express

Tags: express, routes, ejs

i am creating an online-store in which i have page with products , on the left side of the page i want to have filters for the products. At the moment what i am doing i s i have a form which contains the filters and every time i chage something i send information with the chosen filters to the route from which i render the page , process the information and render the page again. The problem is that my route is becoming too busy(too chunky) and i am not shure if this is the right way to do the thing. Here is a short example of what im doing.

```
router.get('/:category/:subCategory/:productID',(req,res)=>{

//i use the variables in the url to send them to the page which im going to render
//to display various information so they are important 

// here i call the data base (mongodb)
//this is just an example it not 1:1 with my code

Products.find().then((result)=>{
//result = all products from the db

Here i do all filtering like under a certain price or color or size whatever

res.render(myEjsPage,{some data i send});

})

}
```

in my Ejs page

```
 <form id="slider-form" action="/<%=mainCategory.id%>/<%=currentSubCategory%>/<%=productId%>"
method="get">
        <input type='range' name ='price' id='price-slider' min='<%=minPrice%>' max='<%=maxPrice%>' value="<%=sliderValue%>">

    </form>
```

I am using js to submit the form , so my point is that i have to call the same route again and again and i have to do all the filtering in that same route , plsus when i call the form i must pass all the information like (category/subCategory/productID) and it jsut looks ugly to me. Is there any way i can send the filters chosen to a separate filtering route , filter them there and render the same page again?

Comment: Shouldn't you be constructing a database query that selects only the items that meet your filter criteria and let the database do your filtering for you?

Comment: the db is pretty nested with objects and arrays , im not experienced with it and i dont know to be honest

Comment: Then, probably time to learn.  It should generally be far more efficient to create a query and let your db deliver you the products you want.  That is one of the main things a database is for (querying).